# IBM MQ and Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am using JMS via IBM MQ. My sender code:

```
 @Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

public void sendPHRq(String msg) {
    jmsTemplate.send(AntiFraudRq, session -> {
        Message message = session.createTextMessage(msg);
        LOGGER.info("1" + message.getJMSCorrelationID());
        LOGGER.info("2" + message.getJMSMessageID());
        return message;
    });
}
```

But in my log I can see only such record:

> 1null
>   2null

How can I get my messageid? Because I'm listening reply queue with another listeners, and shouldn't take their messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can get JMSMessageID after message is sent.

It will be generated by MQ JMS right before sending the message.

Comment: And the correlationId is something you have to set.

Comment: Yes, but only if OP really needs that (creating response, etc.).